# RoR - print count after group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing, group-by

In my Ruby on Rails application, I want to print a count result after I grouped my records in database and I get something like that :

```
{1=>6}
```

In my database there is 6 records, all with the same `user_id`.

Here is my code :

```
Whatever.group(:user_id).count(:user_id)
```

I just want to print **1** how to do this. I tried with `distinct` and `uniq` without any success...

Comment: Since the result is a hash and `1` is the key, I guess `Whatever.group(:user_id).count(:user_id).keys` should return `1`. Give it a go

Comment: @Bala you are almost right. I managed to print `[1]` with `Whatever.group(:user_id).count(:user_id).keys()` (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) with your proposal). Is it possible to remove [ and ] and just keep the number ? Thanks !

Comment: just use `Whatever.group(:user_id).count(:user_id).keys[0]`

Comment: Thank you it doest the work ! Sorry for my basic question I'm new to Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

```
('a'..'b').group_by { |i| i * 2 }          #=> {"aa"=>["a"], "bb"=>["b"], "cc"=>["c"]}
('a'..'c').group_by { |i| i * 2 }.keys     #=> ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
('a'..'c').group_by { |i| i * 2 }.keys[0]  #=> "aa"
```

Comment: This is actually dealing with ActiveRecord's `group` method, not the `group_by` from Enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to compact that down to a useful result:

```
Whatever.group(:user_id).count.keys.join(',')
```

This will handle the case where you have more than one user in the result set.

The `count(:user_id)` part is redundant unless you're counting based on other conditions. Just use `count` instead.

Comment: Assuming the result set has multiple values, this is perfect.

Comment: This method will always produce an array. It may have zero or more values. Compacting it down with `join` seems like the safest bet.